# SqlDataAdapter Insert poor performance

Tags: .net, sql-server, performance, ado.net, sqldataadapter

I wrote some payroll processing software which ultimately writes data out to a SQL Server table using `SqlDataAdapter.Insert()`.  (I am using the default Insert command created with `SqlCommandBuilder()`.)  I am using the .NET Framework 4 on Windows 7, writing to SQL Server 2008 (not R2) Std Edition x64 SP3.  The problem is, I am only seeing about 2 Mbps throughput from my PC (Dell Optiplex 990 Core i7) to the SQL Server (NICs on my PC and the server are GB Enet but there are some 100Mbps switches in between for an unfortunate bottleneck, but still - 100Mbps).  I can copy a file from my PC to the server where SQL Server is running and I have no throughput problems - I can get very close to 100 Mbps throughput there.  I put the database on another LAN SQL Server running 2008 R2 and there I manage to get 5 Mbps throughput, but still - very slow.  My PC's CPU is near 0 when the `Insert()` command is running.  I tried to increase and decrease the **Packet Size** parameter in the `SqlConnection.ConnectionString` property, but that did nothing.

If I perform a `SELECT * FROM <table>` from SSMS on my PC to the SQL Server in question, I can get about 45 Mbps sustained throughput.

I'm not sure where to look next for the culprit - any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: How many rows have been modified when you perform the update? The Update command only processes changed rows. Also why are you doing a `Select * from <table>` and not `Select * from <table> where filterColumn = @filter` If you are querying enough rows to max out your network card, you likely can optimize the queries.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - total brain aneurism there - I meant really `Insert()`. Question has been fixed.

Comment: Ok, how many rows are you inserting at once?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain between 2000-4000.

Comment: Oh yea, you should definitely not be using `Insert()`, that is generating 2000-4000 individual `INSERT INTO` statements. Each statement requires SQL Server do things like check for it's unique key collisions and whatnot. See my answer on how to use SqlBulkCopy which is equivalent to SQL's [`BULK INSERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) so it does those contraint checks once at the end of each batch (the default batch size is "infinite" but is adjustable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SqlDataAdapter's Insert does its records one at a time, if you are inserting a lot of records you should be using [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) instead to mitigate the overhead of doing those inserts.

```
using (SqlConnection destinationConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    destinationConnection.Open();
    using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy =
               new SqlBulkCopy(destinationConnection))
    {
        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = destTableName;
        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(sourceDataTable);
    }
}
```